# Graphql query request URL is to large, and i get a status response of 400 Bad Request

Tags: reactjs, graphql

My issue is because I have a query that is to big when my configurator runs the getCartDetails.graphql file. In Chrome, under Network, my Graphql call has a 400 Bad Request as its to big to handle it.
My question is, how to split this file, so it doesn't cause this issue?

[image]

I have tried to create two seperate files where I import the main graphql file.
First half and second halt, basically to split the main file into 2.
And then call the new merged file where I need it.
But im not sure this is the correct way in doing it.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thank you!

My main graphql file looks like this:

```
query getCartDetails($cartId: String!) {
    cart(cart_id: $cartId) {
        id
        items {
            id
            configuration_id
            configuration_short_id
            threekit_image
            created_at
            updated_at
            measurement_status {
                status
                is_expired
                date
                created_by
                messages
                measurement_id
            }
            product {
                id
                name
                sku
                small_image {
                    url
                    label
                }
                price {
                    regularPrice {
                        amount {
                            value
                        }
                    }
                }
                upsell_products {
                    id
                    name
                    sku
                }
                options_container
                uses_configurator
                classification
            }
            extension_attributes {
                kashiyama_quote_item {
                    brand
                    fabric_name
                    item_type
                    item_name
                    model_number
                    season
                    options {
                        part_id
                        part_label
                        model
                        model_label
                        multiplication_factor
                        options {
                            option_label
                            option_id
                            option_value_id
                            option_value_label
                        }
                    }
                    extra_part_options {
                        extra_part_id
                        part_id
                        options {
                            option_id
                            option_value_id
                            price
                        }
                    }
                    extension_attributes {
                        measurement {
                            created_at
                            updated_at
                            options {
                                configurations {
                                    part_id
                                    part_label
                                    tryon_size
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            prices {
                price {
                    currency
                    value
                }
                row_total {
                    currency
                    value
                }
            }
            quantity
            ... on ConfigurableCartItem {
                configurable_options {
                    id
                    option_label
                    value_id
                    value_label
                }
            }
        }
        prices {
            grand_total {
                value
                currency
            }
            subtotal_including_tax {
                value
                currency
            }
            subtotal_excluding_tax {
                value
                currency
            }
            applied_taxes {
                amount {
                    value
                    currency
                }
                label
            }
            discounts {
                amount {
                    value
                    currency
                }
                label
            }
        }
        applied_store_credit {
            enabled
            current_balance {
                value
                currency
            }
            applied_balance {
                value
                currency
            }
        }
        applied_gift_cards {
            code
            expiration_date
            current_balance {
                value
                currency
            }
            applied_balance {
                value
                currency
            }
        }
        applied_coupons {
            code
        }
        applied_gift_cards {
            code
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I tried but im not sure is correct:

```
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxhDM.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxhDM.png)
```

Comment: What do you mean with too big to handle? 
From my knowledge graphql requests are normally sent as `POST` and with the query as payload, should not be an issue in this case.

Comment: Hi, i have updated my question with a picture of the issue above. As you can see the request URL is huge...

Comment: Look up how to configure your client to use `POST` instead and you are golden my friend

Comment: Thank you @Disco. Gonna talk to my back-end and modify the apolloclient method.